# I get an "No such file or directory" error while installing pyttsx3

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to install pyttsx3 in python but I get a repeated error (below). I have already installed wheels.

How can I debug this issue?

```
    error is:-Collecting pyttsx3
        Using cached pyttsx3-2.84-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
        Collecting pyobjc>=2.4
  Using cached pyobjc-6.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.9 kB)
Collecting comtypes; "win32" in sys_platform
  Using cached comtypes-1.1.7.zip (180 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording==6.1
  Using cached pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording-6.1.tar.gz (63 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\choud\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\choud\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-caww08le\\pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\choud\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-caww08le\\pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\choud\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-caww08le\pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\choud\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-caww08le\pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\choud\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-caww08le\pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording\setup.py", line 27, in <module>   
        Extension(
      File "C:\Users\choud\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-caww08le\pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording\pyobjc_setup.py", line 408, in Extension
        os_level = get_os_level()
      File "C:\Users\choud\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-caww08le\pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording\pyobjc_setup.py", line 218, in get_os_level
        pl = plistlib.readPlist("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist")
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\plistlib.py", line 99, in readPlist
        with _maybe_open(pathOrFile, 'rb') as fp:
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\plistlib.py", line 82, in _maybe_open
        with open(pathOrFile, mode) as fp:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: @MatthewMiles: thank you for your edit. Minor feedback: it looks like, in order to shorten the title, you added the formulation of "please help me with X". In general editors tend to think of that phrase as having a pleading quality about it, and it lacks agency, implying that the writer wants someone to do their work for them. Since some readers may see this request as needy, they may downvote as a result, not knowing that they are not the question author's own words. Better formulations are "How to X" or "How can I X".

Comment: /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist seems like a Mac path, not a Windows one.

Comment: What command(s) did you execute? Can you share some information on your environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

option 1 Uninstall and reinstall python

Than run command line

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

Option 2

install a IDE with python build in and has a package manager